# Replace something inside CDATA with PHP

Tags: php, regex, cdata

I want to replace `chr(10)` with `&#xA;` with PHP within

`<!CDATA[[Text

test

test]]>`

But I'm very poor in REGEX.

Comment: This is very unclear. Can you explain in more detail?

Comment: I have an XML. There are different nodes with values in CDATA. Within the CDATA there are "line feeds"/"chr(10)". I want to replace this line feeds with the corresponding HTML entity "&#xA;".

Comment: Why bother? It's a CDATA block - you don't have to encode entities in a CDATA block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$xml = "cc\n<!CDATA[[Text\ntest\ntest]]>\naa\nbb\n";
$callback = function($m) {
    return '<!CDATA[[' . preg_replace("~" . chr(10) . "~s", '&#xA;', $m[1]) . ']]>';
};
echo preg_replace_callback('~<!CDATA\[\[(.+?)\]\]>~s', $callback, $xml);
```

p.s. you can probably do it without preg_replace_callback, but it looks nicer than to put all logic into preg_replace...

Answer (score 0):

Why use RegEx?

```
$final = str_replace( chr(10), '&#xA;', $cdata );
```

Comment: I have a hole XML with different nodes with values in CDATA. Within the CDATA there are "line feeds"/"chr(10)". I want to replace this line feeds with the corresponding HTML entity "&#xA;".

Comment: How are you parsing this feed? Loop through the nodes and use my above snippet on each node